# Specify a variable implementing 2 interfaces in .net

Tags: .net, vb.net, clr

Is is possible to implement a type specifier with 2 interfaces in .net?  Something like:

```
Public Sub New(obj as ICollection and INotifyCollectionChanged)
    ''Initialize Code
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can with generic constraints; for example in c#:

```
public void Something<T>(T obj)
    where T : IFoo, IBar
{....}
```

Then `Something(value)` will work only when `value` is typed as something that implements both `IFoo` and `IBar`.

Comment: Thanks Mark, this is exactly what I need.  In Vb.net you can add the multiple constraints inside curly braces. See http://geekswithblogs.net/TechnicalDebtor/archive/2008/11/18/vb.net-generics-with-multiple-constraints.aspx

Comment: Apparently only when defining a Generic type. Not when trying to pass to a function.  I.e. you can't do this:
`Public Function Foo(x as {iBar, iBaz}) As Boolean`

Answer (score 6):

No, you will have to define an interface that inherits from both of your desired interfaces.

```
Public Interface IMyCombinedInterface
    Inherits IColllection, INotifyCollectionChanged

End Interface
```

Comment: Thanks Jon.  If I implement IMyCombinedInterface, I cant send in a standard ObservableCollection to the constructor  because it doesn't implement IMyCombindeInterface.  Is a limitation of the language, or am I missing something?